# Refresh div without reload the page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have a page in php and I need to refresh only a div of this page

```
<body>
 .... page code here ....
?><div id="chattext">
            <div id="list"><ul><?php
                echo "ttt ".time();
                ... code php ...
</body>
```

In head tag I hage this code

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup(
    {
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#chattext').hide();
            //$('#loading').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            //$('#loading').hide();
            $('#chattext').show();
        },
        success: function() {
            //$('#loading').hide();
            $('#chattext').show();
        }
    });        
    var url='index.php';
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {            
        $('#chattext').load(url + '#list');
    }, 3000);
});
```

The problem is that che the first time reload all page inside the block and only from the second time reload correctly only the div.... Why??? how can I resolve the problem???

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear enough. Please rephrase.

Comment: what does your php code return? just `LI`s? `$('#chattext').load(url + '#list');` this looks weird to me. why not just: `$('#list').load(url);` ?

Comment: @Alex [learn about page fragments with jquery load.](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: @epascarello thank you, so that line should be `$('#chattext').load(url + ' #chattext');` or `$('#list').load(url + ' #list');` then? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code where you load the page fragment

```
$('#chattext').load(url + '#list');
```

It needs to have a space between the url and the fragment identifier

```
$('#chattext').load(url + ' #list');
```